I wanna create a none window-less shortcut in a script
I have few shortcuts in my Win-10 pc.
They all work fine, but they show this window for a second or so.
I've edited all of them to window style 7 but the issue is still there.
What should I change in order to get an invisible window for each one ?
Thank you
$Links = GCI "D:\*.lnk" -EA:0
foreach ($Link in $Links) {
        # Display the current shortcut's full path
    Write-Output $Link.FullName
        # Edit the shortcut
    $WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($Link.FullName)
    # Set target path and working directory
    $Shortcut.WindowStyle = 7
        # Save changes
    $Shortcut.Save()
}


they show this window . i don't understand. what do you mean?

I have few shutdown shortcuts.
Each time I use a shortcut I see the CMD window for a second.
so I want to edit my shortcut in such a way in which it wouldn't open any window at all.
I ask what should I fill in window style in order to get it ?

May I see the contents of your shutdown code? so I can help.

Without editing it using powershell script

Besides minimizing the window, shortcuts aren't capable of completely hiding a window for the console programs they launch, such as shutdown.exe that I assume you're calling. Instead, a common solution is to point the shortcut to an intermediary program that can hide the console window of the real program you want to run. I wrote bhstart to do this, and you could set a shortcut target to e.g. bhstart shutdown /r /t 0 or whatever you like.

Well, I have about 10 shortcuts.. It's unclear to me if the CMD window I see for a second is preventable or not.
one shourtcut I have is
Shutdown /R /T 0 /F

See How to run PowerShell script without terminal window?
